# Disable wordpress reordering functions in backend screen element

Tags: wp-admin

Does anyone know how to disable WordPress reorder button? I mean the **up and down arrow** (located in the upper right corner of the image attached below), and not the collapse button. So the box will stay at the default original position. Fyi, I'm using the classic editor plugin.

[image]

It will be nice if this can be solved without a plugin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the following CSS to an admin.css file (name it whatever you like but it has to be a css file that applies to the admin.

You need the following in that file:

```
.order-lower-indicator,
.order-higher-indicator{
    display:none;
}
```

To enqueue a stylesheet properly in the admin:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

It's the same basic process as enqueuing for the front end but you're just applying a different action: `do_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', string $hook_suffix );`